# Single controller transferring Rigidbody2D velocity

Tags: unity-game-engine, velocity, gameobject

I am making a Unity game where you are a player but can transform into a ball by pressing the "f" key. The way I do this is with one central gameObject with a script that controls the player, and ball game objects. I have code for the player movement at the beginning but my problem occurs when I switch the game objects. I set one to active, and the other to not active which works. But I can't transfer one gameObject's velocity to the other. Transferring the position works, and I use basically the same method to switch the velocity.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TransformerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Player Vars
    public GameObject player;
    public Rigidbody2D playerRB;

    // Ball Vars
    public GameObject ball;
    public Rigidbody2D ballRB;

    public bool playerActive = true;

    
    // Player Movement Vars
    public bool grounded = true;

    public float speed = 5;

    public float jumpHeight = 5;

    float moveVelocity;

    // Collision Detection
    void OnTriggerEnter2D()
    {
        grounded = true;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D()
    {
        grounded = false;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Swaping sprites
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            // Set player to active
            if (playerActive)
            {
                playerActive = false;
                ball.SetActive(true);
                player.SetActive(false);

                // Transform and velocity
                ball.transform.position = player.transform.position;
                ballRB.velocity = playerRB.velocity;
            }

            // Set ball to active
            else
            {
                playerActive = true;
                ball.SetActive(false);
                player.SetActive(true);

                // Transform and velocity
                player.transform.position = ball.transform.position;
                playerRB.velocity = ballRB.velocity;
            }
        }

        // Player movement
        if (playerActive)
        {
            moveVelocity = 0;

            // Jumping
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                if (grounded)
                {
                    playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(playerRB.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
                }
            }

            // Left/Right Movement
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                moveVelocity = -speed;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                moveVelocity = speed;
            }

            playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(moveVelocity, playerRB.velocity.y);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't really think of anything else to try. I can't find any tutorials on this on YouTube or other sources either. Go easy on me I'm new to Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is causing your problem:

```
...

// Set player to active
if (playerActive)
{
    playerActive = false;
    ball.SetActive(true);
    player.SetActive(false);

    // Transform and velocity
    ball.transform.position = player.transform.position;
    ballRB.velocity = playerRB.velocity;
}

// Set ball to active
else
{
    playerActive = true;
    ball.SetActive(false);
    player.SetActive(true);

    // Transform and velocity
    player.transform.position = ball.transform.position;
    playerRB.velocity = ballRB.velocity;
}

...
```

**Problem:** when you deactivate an object with a `Rigidbody` component:

- Any velocity it previously had is reset to `(0, 0, 0)`.
- Any velocity assigned to it when it's still inactive is ignored.

**Solution:** I will call the objects "sender object" and "receiver object". The sender object must transfer its own velocity to the receiver object. To solve this problem, you can follow these steps:

1. Make sure both the sender object and receiver object are active.
2. Assign the receiver object's velocity with the sender object's velocity value.
3. Deactivate the sender if you wish.

```
...

if (playerActive)
{
    playerActive = false;

    // 1. Activate the ball object
    ball.SetActive(true);

    // 2. Transfer velocity
    ball.transform.position = player.transform.position;
    ballRB.velocity = playerRB.velocity;

    // 3. Deactivate the player object
    player.SetActive(false);
}
else
{
    playerActive = true;

    // 1. Activate the player object
    player.SetActive(true);

    // 2. Transfer velocity
    player.transform.position = ball.transform.position;
    playerRB.velocity = ballRB.velocity;

    // 3. Deactivate the ball object
    ball.SetActive(false);
}

...
```

Read more about your problem:

- [Why does Rigidbody.OnDisable() reset the velocity?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1399132/why-does-rigidbodyondisable-reset-the-velocity.html).
- [When it's inactive, there are no physics objects present in the physics engine at all so properties that are not serialized (volatile state) such as linear/angular velocities are lost anyway.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/set-rigidbody-velocity-in-fixedupdate-or-start.908045/)

Comment: I see why this would work. So just to summarize, because I set the player object to inactive, its velocity is (0 , 0 , 0). So when I copy it to the ball's velocity, the ball just stops moving. The transfer the velocity when both of the gameObjects are active, then deactivating the gameObject that shouldn't be active.